# Run downloaded java file on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I run a java file I've downloaded on eclipse ?

I'm really new to java, so please if you could keep the instructions as detailed and  simple as possible, it would be appreciated.

Comment: What? What java file? A `.java` file? A plugin?

Comment: Maybe this would help if it's java class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934137/how-to-run-single-java-file-from-a-project-in-eclipse

Comment: can you share the java file that you have downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean the *.java source file? If so, first you create a new project in eclipse. Then add the java file to that project. Then on menu bar select Project -> Build Project. Then right click on that java file (in the Package Explorer), select Run -> Java Application