# Java - run packages from command prompt using simplified class

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac

I have a few packages and class how do i run a package called HappyFamilies in command prompt by just typing java HappyFamilies??

./folder$ java HappyFamilies

[image: test]

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is eclipse, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934137/how-to-run-single-java-file-from-a-project-in-eclipse

Comment: You don't run packages. You run a class. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

From your package explora I have understood ,HappyFamilies is not a package ,it's a java class. To run it from command prompt

```
 javac /absolute_path_name/HappyFamilies.java
```

after successful compilation

```
 java /absolute_path_name/HappyFamilies
```

---

Comment: no i don't want to run by java /absolute_path_name/HappyFamilies
I wanna it to be run as java HappyFamilies when I'm in the pwd.

Comment: your question is not clear, please say what's the exact problem and what you actually want to know?